# reactnative issue of installing

Tags: java, android, react-native, gradle

**hii am trying to run a app o react-native on android and getting this error i have tried multiple time and i am using android 12 google api intell 31**

****goelayu4@goelayu4-Inspiron-14-5420:****~/Documents/hisabkaroDevFrontend-main$ npx react-native run-android
warn Package rn-fetch-blob contains invalid configuration: "dependency.hooks" is not allowed. Please verify it's properly linked using "react-native config" command and contact the package maintainers about this.
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file '/home/goelayu4/Documents/hisabkaroDevFrontend-main/android/settings.gradle' (/home/goelayu4/.gradle/caches/7.5.1/scripts/lf5cmm155yzxzgc98a65emce).

> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 63

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 743ms

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file '/home/goelayu4/Documents/hisabkaroDevFrontend-main/android/settings.gradle' (/home/goelayu4/.gradle/caches/7.5.1/scripts/lf5cmm155yzxzgc98a65emce).

> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 63

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

the app is causing the emulator to start but the error is at the time it start to install in it

Comment: i think you need to update your Java installation to the latest version

Answer (score 0):

Try again after gradle version updation and then clean your build cache by
' ./gradlew clean ' .
dont forgot to sync the gradle with your project.